# How do I make my flex container continue on the same line rather than taking up a whole new row like beside a logo on the website?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend, tailwind-css

How can I get a flex container on a same line rather than taking up a whole new row like when I have a logo on the left end of the page and wants to add a flex container to its right but even when I use `inline-flex` it still takes up a whole new row and I'm not very sure how I can implement the way Ive in my mind. I've attached a pic for reference regarding the same. Also I"m using tailwind css to style in a react based project so my code has elements that require other routings and paths to be viewed properly but the html part of the code is what I have attached below along with the styling I used.

How I intend to implement but instead how its being implemented

[image: How I intend to implement but instead how its being implemented]

```html
<div>

  <body class="box-border m-0 p-0">
    <header>
      {user?(

      <div>

        <Link to="/main"><img class="ml-4 mt-8 w-48 bg-yellow-600" src={WorxaImg} alt="logo" /></Link>


        <div class="inline-flex bg-red-700 flex-wrap w-[320px] gap-5">






          <div class="self-start ">
            <input class="bg-green-600 ml-4 w-[10vw] " type="text" placeholder="Search" value={value} onChange={onChange}/> {/* <label>Location {location}</label> */} {/* <button onClick={()=> onSearch(value)} className="ui primary button">search</button>            */}
          </div>

          <div>
            <select class="ml-6 mr-20" type="text" placeholder="Location" name='location' id='location' value={location} onChange={onChangeLocation}>
              <option value="">Select your option</option>
              { locations.map((location,i)=>{ return(
              <option>{location.city}</option>
              ) }) }
            </select>
          </div>


          {jobs .filter((item) => { const searchTerm = value.toLowerCase(); const fullName = item.catogory.toLowerCase(); return ( searchTerm && fullName.startsWith(searchTerm) && fullName !== searchTerm ); }) .slice(0, 10) .map((item) => (

          <Link to={ '/main/'+item.catogory}> {item.catogory}

          <div onClick={()=> onSearch(item.catogory)} key={item.catogory}>
            <Link to={ '/main/'+item.catogory}> {item.catogory}</Link>

          </div>
          </Link>
          ))} {worker .filter((item) => { const searchTerm = value.toLowerCase(); const fullName = item.name.toLowerCase(); return ( searchTerm && fullName.startsWith(searchTerm) && fullName !== searchTerm ); }) .slice(0, 10) .map((item) => (

          <Link to={ '/main/'+item.job+ '/'+item._id}>
          <div onClick={()=> onSearch(item.name)} key={item.name}>
            <Link to={ '/main/'+item.job+ '/'+item._id}> {item.name},{item.job}{item.sjob!=='none'?','+item.sjob:''}</Link>

          </div>
          </Link>
          ))}
          <div>
            <Link to='/registerworker'><i>{(user.type==="employee")?(<div >Update Worker</div>):(<div class="bg-pink-700"> Test</div>)}</i></Link>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button class="bg-yellow-600" onClick={onLogout}>
                                <i>Sign out</i>
                                </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Link to='/profile'><i class="bg-green-700">Profile</i></Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can't really decipher the problem from the code you provided. Try to post enough to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `flex flex-row`  to outermost div but inside of `<body>`.

Below is the code, see whether it works or not for you.

```
<div>

  <body class="box-border m-0 p-0">
    <header>
      {user?(

      <div class="flex flex-row space-x-5">

        <Link to="/main"><img class="ml-4 mt-8 w-48 bg-yellow-600" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-aets/week5-triangle.png" alt="logo" /></Link>


        <div class="flex bg-red-700 flex-wrap w-[320px] gap-5">

          <div class="self-start">
            <input class="bg-green-600 ml-4 w-[10vw] " type="text" placeholder="Search" value={value} onChange={onChange}/> {/* <label>Location {location}</label> */} {/* <button onClick={()=> onSearch(value)} className="ui primary button">search</button>            */}
          </div>

          <div>
            <select class="ml-6 mr-20" type="text" placeholder="Location" name='location' id='location' value={location} onChange={onChangeLocation}>
              <option value="">Select your option</option>
              { locations.map((location,i)=>{ return(
              <option>{location.city}</option>
              ) }) }
            </select>
          </div>


          {jobs .filter((item) => { const searchTerm = value.toLowerCase(); const fullName = item.catogory.toLowerCase(); return ( searchTerm && fullName.startsWith(searchTerm) && fullName !== searchTerm ); }) .slice(0, 10) .map((item) => (

          <Link to={ '/main/'+item.catogory}> {item.catogory}

          <div onClick={()=> onSearch(item.catogory)} key={item.catogory}>
            <Link to={ '/main/'+item.catogory}> {item.catogory}</Link>

          </div>
          </Link>
          ))} {worker .filter((item) => { const searchTerm = value.toLowerCase(); const fullName = item.name.toLowerCase(); return ( searchTerm && fullName.startsWith(searchTerm) && fullName !== searchTerm ); }) .slice(0, 10) .map((item) => (

          <Link to={ '/main/'+item.job+ '/'+item._id}>
          <div onClick={()=> onSearch(item.name)} key={item.name}>
            <Link to={ '/main/'+item.job+ '/'+item._id}> {item.name},{item.job}{item.sjob!=='none'?','+item.sjob:''}</Link>

          </div>
          </Link>
          ))}
          <div>
            <Link to='/registerworker'><i>{(user.type==="employee")?(<div >Update Worker</div>):(<div class="bg-pink-700"> Test</div>)}</i></Link>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button class="bg-yellow-600" onClick={onLogout}>
                                <i>Sign out</i>
                                </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Link to='/profile'><i class="bg-green-700">Profile</i></Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</div>
```